# merge data between objects, match key values

Tags: javascript

Here's a sample of the data

```
featuredPosts = [
  { 'order': 1, 'id': 23 },
  { 'order': 2, 'id': 12 }, 
]
```

and here's the more complex data

```
allPosts = [
  { 'id': 12, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' },
  { 'id': 13, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' },
  ...
  { 'id': 23, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' },
  ...
]
```

Is there a way to merge data from allPosts into featuredPosts only for the id's existing in featured Posts already without looping through featured posts and through the keys of allPosts? I mean is there a smarter way to do so?

Comment: Hi! Your quoted structures are invalid as shown. Are `featuredPosts` and `allPosts` arrays? If not, what are they?

Comment: Separately: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: It's working for you our solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build up a hashtable (id -> featuredPost):

```
 const hash = {};
 for(const featuredPost of featuredPosts)
   hash[featuredPost.id] = featuredPost;
```

Then go over allPosts and look them up in the hashtable:

```
 for(const post of allPosts)
   if(hash[post.id]) Object.assign(hash[post.id], post);
```

Now `featuredPosts` contains the merged data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method by passing a *callback* function as `argument` in combination with `Object.assign` method.

```js
featuredPosts = [
  { 'order': 1, 'id': 23 },
  { 'order': 2, 'id': 12 },
]
allPosts = [
  { 'id': 12, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' },
  { 'id': 13, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' },
  { 'id': 23, 'title': '...', 'content': '...' }
]

var merged = featuredPosts.concat(allPosts).reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x.id] = Object.assign(acc[x.id] || {}, x);
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.keys(merged).map(key => merged[key]));
```